# How do i hide MAC address?

Tags: linux

i wanna hide my system MAC address because linux system people are using my MAC address and they are using Internet, for that reason i need help of hiding MAC address on centos 5.

Note: all people are in root they are using my IP and MAC address and they are adding route table of proxy default IP.

Thanks & regards,

Vidyadhara C

Comment: You mean your sysadmins are using your MAC for...? Who are you trying to keep out of your system? And what do you mean everyone is root?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "hide" your MAC address from other hosts on the same broadcast domain, as the MAC address is needed to be able to send packets to your host.  Outside of the same broadcast domain, your MAC address shouldn't be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all your physical network interfaces - then you'll have no MACs to hide!

You do know that all networking requires MACs right? and that they're inherently advertised.

I think you have a different problem here, in terms of the whole 'everyone using root' and them being able to mess with your routing table - I think you need to deal with that first.